# Request Permission for Library in WKWebView with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a function that would like to retrieve photos from the library on wkwebview. But when I select the image, the application does not ask for library permissions, although I have declared it in info.split. Do I have a way for the application to ask for library permissions when I choose a photo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask permission formally so the user has a chance to decide whether to allow your app to access the photos.
There are many ways to do this, but here is an example:

```
func configureGalleryAccess() {
    print("configure called")
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .authorized {
        print("app was previously authorized")
        self.postAuthorizationLoadController()
    } else {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(_ status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
            print("configure completion called")
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized")
                self.postAuthorizationLoadController()
            case .denied:
                print("PHAuthorizationStatusDenied")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined")
            case .restricted:
                print("PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted")
            }
        })
    }
}

/// Called after permission has been granted.
func postAuthorizationLoadController() { }
```